# Send a confirmation email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to send an order confirmation email from the thankyou page.
I would like to send it to the customer and to the merchant.
I am looking for a WC function to do this.
In thankyou.php, i have to write a hook that call the mailing  function of WC to send an order confirmation email.
For exemple :

```
add_action ('woocommerce_thankyou', "send confirmation email");
```

I'm trying to do this because woocommerce do not send it automaticly. 
I use wpmail SMTP. 
when i send it from the order page of the admin with action->sendmail, mailing Works fine.
so, the problem seems to be that WC doesnt send any mail.

So, the question is:
How can i do to send automaticly an email confirmation from thankyou page using a hook?
Can someone help me please?

Thank you very much for the support.

Comment: The question is : what is the method to use to send a confirmation email with a hook on thank you page, by manualy, i Mean i call thé method directly by myself, it is not automatic .

Comment: Normally woocommerce send automatic emails when an order is incoming with **'New Order'** notification email. If not you got some troubles with your wordpress/woocommerce installation, your settings, your theme, a particular plugin or your hosting...

Comment: Yes,you are right, if it does not work it may be because there is a trouble somewhere, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if it can help, i found a solution:

i use the Class Mailer

```
   $mailer=WC()->mailer();// new instance of mailer class
   $mails = $mailer->get_emails();// it returns the created emails
    if(!empty($mails)){
      foreach($mails as $mail){ // for each created email, we check its type
        if($mail->id=='customer_processing_order'){
            $mail->trigger($order->id);//i send the mail
        }
```

now i would like to send one to the merchant because a new order has been created

i tried

```
else if($mail->id='new_order')
        {
            $mail->trigger($order->id);
        }
```

but it sends all types of mails, somebody has an idea of what is the exact method id for sending à new order created email to the merchant?